# Fourier Series Transformation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, fourier-analysis

I have a question regarding the following:

> > Compute the Fourier transform of $f(x)=xe^{-2x^2}$, $x\in\mathbb{R}$.

The Fourier Transform of $f(x)$ is given by $\mathcal{F}\{f(x)\}=\mathbb{F}(\omega) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)e^{-i\omega x}dx$. As a result, this is what I have:

\begin{eqnarray}
\mathcal{F}\{f(x)\}=\mathbb{F}(\omega) & = &\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x)e^{-i\omega x}dx\\
& =& \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}xe^{-2x^2}e^{-i\omega x}dx\\
& =& \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}xe^{-2x^2-i\omega x}dx\\
\end{eqnarray}

This is where I am stuck. Going about solving for the frequency equation, $\mathbb{F}(\omega)$.

Thank you for your time and thanks in advance for any feedback.

Answer (score 2):

\begin{eqnarray}
\mathbb{F}(\omega) & =& \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}xe^{-2x^2}e^{-i\omega x}dx\\
& =&-2i \int_{0}^{\infty}xe^{-2x^2}\sin(\omega x)dx\\
& =&(-i/4) (\pi/2)^{1/2}\omega \exp(-\omega^2/8) 
\end{eqnarray}

Answer (score 0):

\begin{eqnarray}
\mathcal{F}\{e^{-ax^2}\}=\mathbb{F}(\omega) & = &\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-ax^2}e^{-i \omega x}dx\\
& =& \frac{1}{\sqrt{2a}}e^{\frac{-\omega^2}{4a}}\\
\end{eqnarray}

$$\frac{d}{d\omega}(\mathcal{F}\{e^{-ax^2}\})=\frac{d}{d\omega}(\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-ax^2}e^{-i \omega x} dx)=-i\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}xe^{-ax^2}e^{-i \omega x} dx$$

Thus 
$$-i\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}xe^{-ax^2}e^{-i \omega x} dx=\frac{d}{d\omega}(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2a}}e^{\frac{-\omega^2}{4a}})$$